# Google cloud Virtual windows machine on free tier?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've been reading Google cloud always free at https://cloud.google.com/free/

Can we install a windows server virtual machine in it to run a small windows forms app on it? Our developer has a small vb.net desktop app that we want to run on it. And as such if it is seldom used, will it still be free?

Answer (score 2):

Well its free but it only provides a micro instance. A Micro instance only has 0.6 Gb ram, which is not enough to run windows.

Comment: True. Also, Windows base images are 50GB in size, while Always Free tier includes quota of only 30GB/month worth of Persistent Disk.